# Force web-mode.el Engine

Tags: web-mode

In my `django` project I use basic `.html` files for my templates.

I want to force the `django` engine from `web-mode.el` so I don't have to constantly change between `.html` and `.djhtml`.

I've tried the following

```
(setq web-mode-engines-alist
      '(("django"    . "\\.html\\'"))
      )
```

with no luck.

Anyone had any success in this? Should I try out a different plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration works for me.

You can force the engine like this:

```el
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda ()
 (web-mode-set-engine "django"))
```

Comment: Also can add a condition that matches file etension `.html`. Because the op may want to use `web-mode` in other files.